# Numpy fails to import except in Admin command prompt

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I recently updated numpy on Windows using pip and encountered a strange problem. After the update when I run python from an Admin prompt and import numpy, it works fine. But when I import it from a normal non-admin prompt, I get this error:

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 190, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .index_tricks import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\index_tricks.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import function_base
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 2489, in <module>
    def corrcoef(x, y=None, rowvar=1, bias=np._NoValue, ddof=np._NoValue):
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute '_NoValue'
```

And when I tried again it changes to

```
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 190, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .index_tricks import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\index_tricks.py", line 6, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'core'
```

All the library files are in the file system although it sounds like it is unable to find `numpy.core`.

One possibly relevant fact is that python is installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5` rather than in the root directory. (This is the default install location as of 3.5, but has caused minor problems before.) I wonder if there could be a problem with file or directory permissions?

Also I tried reinstalling and even downgrading back to 1.10.4 (using the binary [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and the problem persisted, although it wasn't there before the upgrade, and I installed it from the same source.

Any ideas on what the issue is?

Comment: Did you write a script called 'numpy.py' as your non-admin user, and saved it where Python might find it instead of the real numpy module?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of Python installed on your computer? What is the output of `import numpy; import os; os.path.abspath(numpy.__file__)` from the prompt that's working?`

Comment: Probably you have a failed install attempt from when you didn't have permission to write to `C:\Program Files (x86)`. The 32-bit version of 3.5.0 wasn't manifested to avoid virtualizing system directories. Check `%LocalAppData%\VirtualStore` for the incomplete NumPy installation. Update to Python 3.5.1 to avoid this problem.

Comment: @eryksum: I think you were right. Is it safe to just delete this folder?

Comment: @eryksum: I deleted it and it worked fine. Then I updated python and it still works fine. Thanks!