# Numpy fails to load in Windows command window. Python version 3.7.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, numpy, anaconda

I recently installed Anaconda3 with Python 3.7.1 on Windows 10. I am also using Python launcher because I also have Python 2.7 installed on my computer. Python Launcher seems to be working correctly.

When using my Spyder IDE that shipped with Anaconda, numpy imports correctly. However, when importing from a "launched" version of Python 3 in the Windows command window I get the following Traceback:

```
c:\>py
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.__file__
'C:\\Python27\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.pyc'
>>>

c:\>py -3 --version
Python 3.7.1

c:\>py -3
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError:
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check these out. 
These might help you.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51091218/9968772
https://stackoverflow.com/q/36732532/9968772
```